# How to make simple log4j configuration?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I want to make to log file to my application.
I try Appach log4j for this. In Java code i says:

```
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(uploadfile.class);
        log.debug("Start");
```

I create file `src\log4j.properties` with:

```
# ***** Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R, A
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100mb
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1000
log4j.appender.R.File=c:/uploaded_files/server.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n


# ***** A is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# ***** A uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry=INFO
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider=INFO
```

I copy this [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890983/simple-log4j-configuration-issue). And i get error:

```
  13.02.2013 9:03:34 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [uploadfile] in context with path [/gis-mrsk-portlet] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
at test.uploadfile.doPost(uploadfile.java:35)
```

What i doing wrong? And how to configure log4j for simple?

**UPDATE**

If i use this config i get log file but its empty:

```
Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL

 CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n

 LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=C:/uploaded_files/LogFile.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems correct.. have you set correctly the log4j Lib in your path?

Comment: What you can tall about my config? Using it what i will get in log?

Comment: Try to remove log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A. With this  configuration you will have your debug, info and error logs on the console (if you're running your application in eclipse) and in your specified file.

Comment: Try to change log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE  with log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

Comment: Your last comment help me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your configuration, the problem is the **non-existant support of log4j for catalina** it's not as easy to get it to work together as it should be. To make log4j work with catalina follow the documentation available at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j.

*EDIT*

To summarize the link I gave:

1. [...] put log4j.jar and log4j.properties into WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes of your web application.
2. Download or build tomcat-juli.jar and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar that are available as an "extras" component for Tomcat. See Additional Components documentation for details. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/extras.html

After following those steps your example should already work.

*/EDIT*

If you want the easy part in logging I would suggest using logback which comes with native servlet support for tomcat based applications. If you want to go one step further in logging: clusterlog.net (full disclosure I own part of that company)

Comment: i cant get log4j example from this site(.

Comment: I just added the relevant paragraph from the link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

It looks like your Apache does not know definition of `org.apache.log4j.LogManager`. Have you put required jar in Apache `classpath`?

Comment: Yeah i see log4j.jar in project libraries.